# How do you get the default insets of NSViews and NSControls?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, nsview

I'm writing some custom layout code to align some `NSView`s. I loop through all the views and set their frame.origin.x to the same value (left alignment), but the views don't look like they're aligned properly. I looked at left aligned views in Interface Builder, and each different class of view has a different frame.origin.x value.

For example, to left align an `NSPopUpButton` with an `NSTextField`, the frame.origin.x value of the `NSPopUpButton` has to be 3 pixels less than that of the `NSTextField`.

I found a method `ibLayoutInset` in `InterfaceBuilderKit.framework` that appears to be what I want, but none of the AppKit views implement the method.

Does anyone know how to get these inset values programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from measuring yourself and building your own table of offsets, you can’t.  This is rather annoying, and it’s probably best to file a bug report, here: http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Thanks. From my experience reporting bugs to Apple, I get the impression that the term "bug report" is slang for "toilet paper" inside Apple; as in "we need some more bug reports for the men's room, because I just used the last of them."

Comment: That’s unfair; there are a lot of dedicated engineers working at Apple, and bug reports really _do_ make a difference.  The problem really is the lack of feedback from Apple, but that’s understandable if you think about things from the other side for a moment or two.